# Why $Cov(\pmb{y}, \pmb{\hat{y}}) = \pmb{y}^T \pmb{\hat{y}}$?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I'm trying to proof some results in Multiple Linear Regression.
In matrix notation, why $Cov(\pmb{y}, \pmb{\hat{y}}) = \pmb{y}^T \pmb{\hat{y}}$?

Comment: Do you have a source for the equality?

Comment: In "Solutions Manual to Accompany Introduction to Linear Regression", 5th edition, Exercise 3.33, the author says this in the page 30.

Comment: This does not look right. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978027/how-to-prove-that-textcovy-i-haty-i-sigma2-h-ii/.

Answer (score 4):

That is simply not true!

$y^T\hat{y}$ can take values larger than 1, and it's not that hard to come with an example. Try the data

$x=(0,1,2,3)$

$y=(6,8.1,9.9,12)$

Estimate the regression model for $y$ on $x$ and see how $y^T\hat{y}$ will be above 340! Correlation between $y$ and $\hat{y}$ stays at $0.9995$ while their covariance is close to $6.5$

Comment: Sorry! I mean the Covariance. I'm editing the post.

Comment: Still not true, Covariance stays at about 6.5 in the example I presented. Indeed, the product $y^t\hat{y}$ always increases with sample size while covariance does not necessarely